# Webcam worked yesterday, no more

Tags: 10.04, laptop, webcam

Along with the rest of the world, I joined google plus right after invitations became available last night. I was able to use my webcam for their hangouts, now I cannot. When I checked lshw I can't find the webcam on the slot it was in last night.

Relevant system info:
OS: ubuntu 10.04
System model: Dell Inspiron 1525
lshw snippets:

> ```
>        *-generic:2 UNCLAIMED
>             description: System peripheral
>             product: xD-Picture Card Controller
>             vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
>             physical id: 9.3
>             bus info: pci@0000:02:09.3
>             version: 12
>             width: 32 bits
>             clock: 33MHz
>             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
>             configuration: latency=64
>             resources: memory:fe3ff600-fe3ff6ff
>        *-generic:3 UNCLAIMED
>             product: Illegal Vendor ID
>             vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
>             physical id: 9.4
>             bus info: pci@0000:02:09.4
>             version: ff
>             width: 32 bits
>             clock: 66MHz
>             capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list
>             configuration: latency=255 maxlatency=255 mingnt=255
>             resources: memory:fe3ff700-fe3ff7ff
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If it is the inbuilt webcam, unscrew the protective frame of the LCD screen (covered by plastic round bumps. Once it's off check for a beige-white connector near the webcam. If it looks like it's kinda out, push it back in again gently with a screw driver.

This affects my dell 1545 also :)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it but I doubt that's it since the laptop was stationary between the time I used it and they time I noticed the issue.

Comment: I know but it was the same with me also. Try using the cheese webcam progam to test if the webcam works locally.

suuo apt-get install cheese

Comment: Got it. Apparently you have to reinstall the plugin twice instead of once.